Software recommendation / comparison website (softwarerecs alternative)
I am looking for a website that allows users to ask for and provide software recommendations (in particular pertaining to software development, i.e. program libraries and developer tools, but if it's more general than that, then that's fine, too) which doesn't share the limitations this site inherits from StackExchange's Q&A format.
E.g., it's obviously bad that answers generally contain multiple recommendations but can only be up/downvoted as a whole. A site built from scratch for recommendations specifically wouldn't have this limitation.
Similarly, free-form text is probably not the best format to represent recommendation requests and responses. A more structured approach could allow automatic generation of comparison tables etc.
Are there any sites like that? It could be more comparison-focused than recommendation-focused as well (because that's what recommendations usually boil down to anyway).

Not 100% what you are looking for, but still worth a visit ... https://alternativeto.net/
